# Replace Conditional with Polymorphism with Spring autowire

Tags: spring

I have this Service code

```
@Service
public class StoreCartService {
public boolean addItem(Cart cart, Long productId, Integer quantity) {
    cart.handleRequest(productId,"+"+quantity);
    return true;
}

public boolean deleteItem(Cart cart, Long productId, Integer quantity) {
    cart.handleRequest(productId,"-"+quantity);
    return true;
}
}
```

That is being called in a controller like this:

```
return storeCartService.addItem(cart,cartItem.getProductId(),cartItem.getQuantity() );
```

and

```
return storeCartService.deleteItem(cart,cartItem.getProductId(),cartItem.getQuantity() );
```

I thought of refactoring it like this:

```
abstract class Item{
abstract boolean processItem(Cart cart, Long productId, Integer quantity);
```

}

```
class CartItemAddition extends Item{
boolean processItem(Cart cart, Long productId, Integer quantity){
    cart.handleRequest(productId,"+"+quantity);
}
}   

class CartItemDeletion extends Item{
boolean processItem(Cart cart, Long productId, Integer quantity){
    cart.handleRequest(productId,"-"+quantity);
}
}
```

in the client code, depends on where you call it...

```
Item item = new CartItemAddition();
```

or

```
Item item = new CartItemDeletion();
```

but then I cant do this because the Service object is being autowired. I cant instantiate it like how I want it to. How do i go about resolving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

you can autowired by name.

```
@Resource(name = "cartItemAddition")
```